# Robolectric fails to assert that true is true

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have finally started to realize that it is a good idea to unit test my Android application (specifically the database operations) and found the Robolectric framework to help me do that. I set up a simple test in `/app/src/test/java/<package>/SanityTest.java`:

```
package <package>;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SanityTest {

    @Test
    public void testTrueIsTrue() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I ran the test with `./gradlew robolectric`:

```
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild
// ...
:app:robolectricClasses UP-TO-DATE
:app:robolectric

<package>.SanityTest > testTrueIsTrue FAILED
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

1 test completed, 1 failed
:app:robolectric FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:robolectric'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///<project_root>/app/build/reports/tests/index.html
```

The stack trace generated by the Robolectric report showed an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://codetidy.com/4195)

**Some other information:**

I'm using

1. Gradle 1.10
2. Android Studio 0.5.7
3. Robolectric 2.2
4. JUnit 4.11

Comment: It told you to see the report at a certain URI. Did you? What did it say?

Comment: Yes, I did. That was in the question. "The stack trace generated by the Robolectric report showed an [`IllegalArgumentException](http://codetidy.com/4195)"

Comment: I'd tried changing the argument `assertTrue(1==1)` `assertFalse(!true)`, etc. Maybe add some other simple test methods as well. Just to see if they all fail or if you can isolate the problem a bit.

Comment: It showed an IllegalArgumentException *where*? The problem is not the test; I believe "Execution failed for task" means it was not even able to run the test. There is a problem with your environment.

Comment: maybe change `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` to `@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)`

Comment: Okay, I just followed the link. The IllegalArgumentException was during class loading, but no indication of what class it was trying to load. Are you sure you have all the necessary jars?

Comment: @DavidConrad By jars, do you mean the Robolectric and JUnit dependencies? Then yes, I have those jars added in Gradle with `androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.+'` and `androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'`. I am also using the [Robolectric plugin](https://github.com/novoda/robolectric-plugin).

Comment: @deanosaur I tried what you said, while changing the deprecated `junit.framework.Assert` to the new `org.junit.Assert`. See [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/473)

Comment: @whowantsaookie I am having the same problem. Have u found a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't.